# Array in Method Header: error ']' expected (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, methods, compiler-errors

I'm quite new to arrays and methods, and I've been seeing this error recurring through several programs: error '[' expected.

In each occasion, it seems to correct itself as I adjust something else, but in this particular case, I am completely stumped.

By the way, I am using several methods and arrays to create a quiz (before you ask, yes, this is an assignment and I agree, a list is a better way to handle this data - but that is not an option).

It is possible that I am not passing the arrays correctly between methods, as I'm a little muddy on that process. From my understanding, in order to send/receive (i.e. import/export) an array or other variable between methods, I must declare that variable/array in the method header parameters.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class H7pseudo
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    //call getAnswerkey method
    getAnswerkey(answerkey[i]);

    //call getAnswers method
    getAnswers(answers[i]);

    //call passed method? necessary or no?
    boolean passed = passed(answerkey[i], answers[i], qMissed[i], points);

    //Print results of grading
    if (passed)
    {
      System.out.println("Congratulations! You passed.");
    }
    else
    {
     System.out.println("Try again, sucka. You FAILED.");
    }

    //call totalPoints
    totalIncorrect(points);

    //call questionsMissed
    questionsMissed(qMissed[i]);
  }

  //get answer key (create answerkey array & export)
  public static void getAnswerkey(answerkey[i])
  {
    //create answerkey array here
    char[] answerkey;

    //determine number of questions (indices)
    answerkey = new char[20];

    //input values (correct answers) for each index
    //for our purposes today, the answer is always 'c'.
    for (int i = 0; i <=20; i++)
    {
      answerkey[i] = 'c';
    }
  }

  //get student answers (create answers array & export)
  public static void getAnswers(answers[i])
  {
    //initialize scanner for user input
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    //create answer array here
    char[] answers;

    //determine number of questions (indices)
    answers = new char[20];

    //prompt for user input as values of each index
    for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
      answers[i] = scan.nextChar();
    }
  }

  //grade student answers (import & compare index values of arrays:answers&answerkey
  //create & export qMissed array
  public static boolean passed(answerkey[i], answers[i], qMissed[i], points)
  {
     int points = 0;

     //create new array: qMissed
     boolean[] qMissed;

     //determine number of questions to be graded
     qMissed = new boolean[20];

     //initialize values for array
     for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
       qMissed[i] = false;
     }

     //cycle through indices of answerkey[i] & answers[i];
     for (int i = 0; i =< 20; i++)
     {
       if (answers[i] == answerkey[i])
       {
         correct = true;
         points = points+1;
         qMissed[i] = true;
       }
       else {
         qMissed[i] = false;
       }
     }

     //evaluate whether or not the student passed (15+ correct answers)
     if (points >= 15)
     {
       passed = true;
     }
     else
     {
       passed = false;
     }
     return passed;
   }

  public static void totalIncorrect(points)
  {
    int missed = 20 - points;
    System.out.println("You missed " + missed + " questions.");
  }


  public static void questionsMissed(qMissed[i])
  {
    // for each index of the array qMissed...
    for (int i = 0; i < qMissed.length; i++)
    {
      //...print correct and false answers.
      system.out.println(i + ": " + qMissed[i] + "\n");
    }
  }


}
```

Comment: What do you think `public static void getAnswerkey(answerkey[i])` should do?

Comment: You might want to consider loops for initialization instead of those massive initialization blocks...

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis: The idea is that getAnswerkey establishes an array that holds the correct value (answer) for each index (question). I put it in a method to keep things organized and tidy. Also, in my inexperience, I'm a little leery of putting an array I want to share between methods in the 'public main'...

Comment: @user3580294 Oh dear, you made me blush. I can't believe I missed that! :-\ Thanks for the sensible advice!

Comment: That's not what I meant. I meant the declaration itself. Deconstruct each part. What is `public`? What is `static`? What is `void`? What is `answerkey[i]` between parentheses? How do you define a method? What are the parts involved?

Answer (score 0):

You can't define array size in the method signature, in Java.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void getAnswerkey(answerkey[i])
```

You can't put anything inside the `[]` in a method declaration. Also, you have to mention the type:

```
public static void getAnswerKey(char[] answerkey)
```

This is not the only reason your code won't work as intended, but I'll leave the rest as part of the exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your method definitions:

```
public static void questionsMissed(qMissed[i])
```

This is wrong. You should define the type of the variable and it should not contain `[i]` like an element of an array. It should be something like this:

```
public static void questionsMissed(int qMissed)
```

Or if you want to pass the array, write it like this:

```
public static void questionsMissed(int[] qMissed)
```

---

Apart of this, there are other several errors in your code:

```
getAnswerkey(answerkey[i]); //answerkey is not defined

getAnswers(answers[i]); //answers is not defined
```

It would be better if you start reading a Java tutorial first.

Comment: @AntonH no, because it uses a single element of the array, not the array.

Comment: @AntonH ok, I read other methods and got confused. In fact, IMO there's no answer that can be written in less than 5 mins that can fix all the problems in OP's code and give him a tutorial about how to program in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I want to vote up Luiggi's answer, but I don't have enough reputation to do that :)

Congrats, cordivia, on getting started with Java!

Here is how an array is declared:

```
type[] arrayName = new type[numberOfElements]
```

For example, you did this right in your method definition for getAnswerkey():

```
char[] answerkey;
answerkey = new char[20];
```

The part in the method definition *inside the parentheses* defines the *kind* of data the method is willing to accept from the *outside*.  So if you don't need to put something into the method to get something out of it, you don't need to put anything in the parentheses.  Define the method like this:

```
getAnswerkey() {
```

...But that's not the whole story.  If you want to *get* something out of the method, it needs to have a *return type* as well.  A *return type* is what you're gonna get out of the method when the method's done doing it's magic.  For example, if you want to get an *int* array out of a method you would do something like this:

```
public static int getTheInteger() {
```

Since you want an array of *chars* from the method, you'll want to do something like this:

```
public static char[] getAnswerkey() {
```

So that's how you get a method to give you something back. If don't want anything back, you put **void**:

```
public static void noMarshmallows() {
```

Now, when you use the method, you're gonna need to do something with what it gives you, or it did all that work for nothing.  So you need to store the *return value* in a variable when you *call* the array (*calling* methods is what you've been doing in **main**).  You know how to store something in a *variable*.  You use the '=' operator:

```
int myVeryFavoriteNumber;
myVeryFavoriteNumber = 5;
```

So, you do the same thing when you're getting something out of an array.  You *assign* the *return value* to a variable.  If you want to do this with an array, do this:

```
int[] myFavs;
myFavs = getMyFavoriteNumbers();
```

Same with *chars*:

```
char[] answerKey;
answerKey = getAnswerKey();
```

Voila!  Your answer key is now right out in the open for the rest of **main** to see :)

Now, if you want to put something *into* a method and have it do something with what you put in, you define a *parameter*.  You know how this works.  It's just like declaring a variable, and that's exactly what it is. Parameters go in the parentheses and only the method using the parameter sees that variable name (it's *local*).  Something like this:

```
public static void plusOneToAll (int[] numbers) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        numbers[i] = numbers[i] + 1;
    }
}
```

Notice **int[] numbers** in the parentheses. The *type* being passed in is **int[]** or integer array. **numbers** is just the parameter name.  It functions just like a variable, but it is declared *locally* (inside the parentheses) and use *locally* (inside the method). So, if you wanted to compare the answers from two arrays and return the number of matches (like a total score for instance), you would do something like this:

```
public static int getTotalScore (char[] correctAnswers, char[] userAnswers) {

    int totalScore = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < correctAnswers.length; i++) {
        if (userAnswers[i] == correctAnswers[i]) {
            totalScore = totalScore + 1;
        }
    }

    return totalScore;
}
```

Notice the return type: **int** (written before the method name). *Inside* the array I'm using the variable **totalScore** to keep track of the number of times the answers match.  The method *takes* two char arrays from the outside and uses them on the inside.  Finally, I *return* an **int**: **totalScore**.  That kicks the value of **totalScore** back out to whatever called it (**main**).

If I might add one last thing: Do yourself a favor and go pick up a copy of *Head First Java*. It's hard to find a good tutorial online and Java textbooks are just plain boring. The Head First series are kind of like coloring books for adults.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for the comprehensive answer. This is a great explanation1 I've now whittled the problem down to just one error! If I may solicit your advice, I'm not sure what the best practice is on SO: should I update the code on this thread? Or post it on a new thread? Or not post the same program twice (because it's bad manners, or just lame)? Please be frank. Thank you again!

Comment: I'm pretty new to Stack Overflow, so I'm not sure what best practice is on that.  However, I do know this: it's good etiquette on Stack Overflow to focus a question to a single issue, so if your last bug would not have been answered by this thread, it's probably best to open a new thread on it.